# Conditional Compile of Generic Methods

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Currently working on a 2-way lookup association generic, sorted by TKey. At some point I hope to have access like the following:

```
public class Assoc<TKey, TValue>
{
     public TKey this[TValue value] { get; }
     public TValue this[TKey value] { get; }
}
```

But obviously when TKey == TValue this will fail. Out of curiosity, is there a conditional compile syntax to do this:

```
public class Assoc<TKey, TValue>
{
     [Condition(!(TKey is TValue))]
     public TKey this[TValue value] { get; }

     [Condition(!(TKey is TValue))]
     public TValue this[TKey value] { get; }

     public TKey Key(TValue value) { get; }

     public TValue Value(TKey value) { get; }
}
```

Comment: When would using the class with TKey == TValue be useful?

Comment: What does `public TKey this[TValue value] { get; }` do? I'm not understanding the purpose of this API.

Comment: @casablanca, Have you ever used `Dictionary<string, string>`? It looks like Jake wants to have something very similar to a dictionary, but with associative search by both key and value.

Comment: I faced a similar problem once. I just used something like `if value.GetType() == typeof(TKey)` in the getter and depending was taking action. But I think you already guessed the alternative...

Comment: @Matthew the key is for sorting, not lookup; slightly different than what you would immediately assume at first impression i suppose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no conditional compiltation based on Generic types.

Generics substitutions are performed at runtime, not compile time.

This is one of the differences between .NET generics and C++ templates.

Generics also don't have the concept of *specialization* that C++ templates have.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cyy67b.aspx

Comment: +1. Note "Generics are resolved at runtime, not compile time." is not exactly true - at compile time methods in generic class need to be properly found (which is exact error Jake's class produces when compiler tries to pick which version of indexer needs to be used).

Comment: Agree with @Alexei; the issue here has nothing to do with runtime behavior of generics.  This is *purely* a matter of method overload resolution, which is a compile-time construct.  In particular, the problem is that with no qualifiers (such as `where TKey: Foo`, etc.) these are both treated by the compiler as `object` and thus the normal method overload collission behavior -- when two methods share the same parameter types (i.e. `object`) -- kicks in.  This is a *compile* time scenario.

Comment: "Generics also don't have the concept of specialization that C++ templates have." - only in C#. After having read ECMA-335, I believe the CLI itself does allow for specialization of generics (though this requires some-degree of language support).